# Quantifying internal consistency with multiple raters and continuous rating scales

Tags: reliability, scales, psychometrics, item-response-theory

I have data from an assessment where people are rated by multiple raters on a set of criteria using a rating scale that is (essentially) interval. All people are rated by all raters.

I believe that each criteria measures an aspect of a unidimensional latent variable, and I'd like to quantify the internal consistency of the assessment. To give a toy example, the data would look like this:

```
Person Rater Criteria1 Criteria2
     A    R1      17.5      25.3
     A    R2      19.4      23.8
     B    R1      26.5      31.2
     B    R2      24.7      33.8
```

If there was only one rater per person then I could simply calculate a statistic like Cronbach's alpha. Intuitively, though, it would seem that having multiple scores per person could inflate the coefficient.

Is there any other way to quantify internal consistency that take into account the fact that there are multiple observations of the same variable per person? I could perhaps take a mean score for each criteria across the raters for each person and calculate Cronbach's alpha (or something similar) from that, but I'd be interested to know if there are any alternatives.

Comment: If each criteria is equal, why not alpha? Each rater is like a question on a scale.

Comment: @JeremyMiles I hadn't thought of trying that. My first two thoughts are 1) would such an approach allow inter-rater reliability (either for consensus or absolute agreement) to bias alpha? 2) I was under the impression that all other things being equal, increasing the number of items will increase alpha; if I have one set of items for each rater then this seems like I might still get an anti-conservative impression of the internal consistency of the assessment.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your first point. Alpha is inter-rater agreement. Alpha is a form of ICC. Second: increasing the number of items increases alpha, because alpha is reliability and increasing the number of items increases reliability.

Comment: @JeremyMiles Perhaps wrongly, I tend to think of internal consistency as saying something about the average correlation between items. With that assumption in mind, it seems plausible that if I had a set of items that only weakly correlated with each other but which each had good inter-rater reliability I could still end up with a high alpha. Similarly, vast numbers of very weakly correlated items could also have a high alpha.

Comment: Inter-rater reliability does say something about the average correlation. It's a function of the average correlation, and the number of ratings (or items in a questionnaire). More items (ratings, tests) with the same average correlation will give a higher reliability. You say "... good inter-rater reliability I could still end up with a high alpha."  Good inter-rater reliability IS high alpha. Vast numbers of weakly correlated items give high alpha because when you have vast numbers of items with low correlation, you have good reliability.

Comment: Look at the bit about standardized alpha: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronbach's_alpha